BaconQrCode can't run in my laravel 10 and latest vesion of php
I'm working on a Laravel project that uses the baconQrCode library to generate QR codes, and I'm encountering the error Class 'BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png' not found when I call my generateUser function (generates a QR code based on a user's UUID). I have PHP version 8.1.10 installed, and I've ensured that the baconQrCode library is included in my composer.json file. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully generate QR codes using PHP 8.1.10?
Here is the relevant part of my code:
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png;
use BaconQrCode\Writer;

public function generateUser($usrID)
{
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('usrID', '=', $usrID)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User not found.');
    }

    $qrdata = [
        'usrLastName' => $user->usrLastName,
        'usrFirstName' => $user->usrFirstName,
        'usrMiddleName' => $user->usrMiddleName,
        'qrCode' => (new Writer(new Png()))->writeString($user->usrUuId),
    ];

    return view('qr.users.print', compact('qrdata'));
}

I've tried to convert the functions of qrcode from laravel7 to Laravel10, but this is the issue I've encountered.

Which version of bacon/bacon-qr-code are you using?

It may be the case that you have upgraded the package bacon/bacon-qr-code to the latest version which removes BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png (source).
Instead use the new ImageRenderer to generate the QR code. Here a example from the docs:
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\ImageRenderer;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\ImagickImageBackEnd;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\RendererStyle\RendererStyle;
use BaconQrCode\Writer;

$renderer = new ImageRenderer(
    new RendererStyle(400),
    new ImagickImageBackEnd()
);
$writer = new Writer($renderer);
$writer->writeFile('Hello World!', 'qrcode.png');

In your specific case you have to adjust the creation of the qrdata array.
// Replace the imports at the top of your file
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\ImageRenderer;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\ImagickImageBackEnd;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\RendererStyle\RendererStyle;
use BaconQrCode\Writer;


// Adjust the generateUser function
$renderer = new ImageRenderer(
    new RendererStyle(400),
    new ImagickImageBackEnd()
);
$qrCodeWriter = new Writer($renderer)

$qrdata = [
    'usrLastName' => $user->usrLastName,
    'usrFirstName' => $user->usrFirstName,
    'usrMiddleName' => $user->usrMiddleName,
    'qrCode' => $qrCodeWriter->writeString($user->usrUuId),
];

